# Restricting the input on just type number?

Tags: reactjs, input

I want just to put a type number in  an input react js, is there any particular function that i should add to restict the input only in number type and to control the max and min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use `<input type="number"/>` for that. This will make the restriction at the HTML level itself.

Comment: thanks! it did help

Comment: @Meriem Can you please mark it as Answer as it resolved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<input type="number" />
```

Check this [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) for more infos on different types

Comment: it was usefull ! thanks